# Is it possible for a magnet to catch a bullet after it is fired?

Tags: engineering

Could a strong enough magnet deflect or stop a bullet?

Comment: Welcome Lost (may I call you by your first name?). Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways. We like to understand here what's going on in your scenario, we call that "worldbuilding context". Each question is required to have that and enough detail to be able to be answered. Could you [edit] to fill out the details.

Comment: You can melt lead with induction, but I wouldn't want to be on the same planet with a machine that can stop a bullet doing so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

short question, short answer: [Mythbusters!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXDLGNKoR2c)

**Can a magnet curve the path of a bullet?**
We sell some incredibly powerful magnets. If a really powerful magnet was placed near the path of a bullet, could it curve the bullet's path? Is it possible?

**Previous Research**
This question has been asked a number of times, both on television and the Internet. Mythbusters investigated it in episode 95, one of their James Bond specials. They fired a bullet above a series of magnets to see if they could alter the bullet’s path. Their test made a bullet tumble end over end, but didn’t change the path much at all.

There’s also some debate on the Internet about how Magneto stopped a bullet in the original X-men movie. Is it possible? What sort of energy would it need? It’s a little silly, debating the physics of a superhero movie, but interesting nonetheless.

Usually, the answer is no.
Does a strong magnet placed very close to a bullet’s path curve it?
Typically, no.

Most bullets aren’t ferromagnetic – they aren’t attracted to magnets. Bullets are usually made of lead, maybe with a copper jacket around them, neither of which sticks to a magnet.

These magnets made a bullet tumble on Mythbusters, but didn't change where it hit the target.
The magnet might impart some force on the bullet via Eddy Currents. The same way a magnet falls slowly through a copper pipe, the magnetic field can induce tiny currents in the electrically conductive material, pushing it a little bit. The problem is that this is a tiny amount of force, exerted on the bullet for only a tiny period of time as it passes over a magnet.

In that Mythbusters episode, they showed how strong magnets didn’t quite curve a bullet’s path, but made it tumble. We suspect this was because eddy currents acted more on the bottom of the bullet, closer to the magnets where the field strength is greater. The direction the bullet tumbled is consistent with this theory.

Still, even this didn’t alter the path of the magnet. It still hit the target in the same spot.

**Stack the odds in favor of success!**
Naturally, we wanted to demonstrate some situation where a magnet could really change the bullet’s path. So we stacked the odds in our favor! To make the bullet curving magnet possible:

We shot a steel BB instead of a lead bullet. This helps because steel is attracted to magnets. Plus, the lighter mass of the BB means we’re fighting less momentum.

We shot the BB from a low powered, pump-action air gun. The lower projectile velocity means it’s easier to change the path.

We also only pumped the gun once, instead of the recommended 3-5 times. The lower air pressure made the initial bullet velocity slower, reducing its momentum.

**The Setup**

The test setup is fairly straightforward. For the baseline, we aimed the air rifle at a target several feet away.

After recording the path of the bullet, we made the same shot with a powerful 3” diameter x 1.5” thick, grade N52 DZ0X8-N52 magnet just below the bullet’s path.  Would we see a difference between the two shots?

**Success!**
The video below shows some great high-speed footage of our results. The magnet was able to alter the path of the BB!

Comment: Can you [edit] this post to be a full answer without needing to follow any links. Links have a unfortunate tendency of going stale with time. As a result we classify link only answers as non-answers and are likely of being deleted.

Comment: but I want to see the video...

Comment: [How could Magneto stop the bullet fired at the police officer's head?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/57207/how-could-magneto-stop-the-bullet-fired-at-the-police-officers-head) "Copper and lead *are* actually magnetic -- more accurately, they're diamagnetic. Thus, *in theory*, a magnetic field in front of the copper-jacketed lead bullet could resist the bullet's motion and, along with a field around it, suspend it in the air."

Answer (score 2):

**No. Yes. Kinda.**

Bullet: 10g, 2000J (~640m/s)

Magnetic field goes down with 1/r³ (if you are farther away than about 10x the diameter of the loop)

**Bullet ferromagnetic, magnet part of target : No.** You could only pull on the bullet, and that would not be helpful, assuming you do not have a specific bullet collecting orifice in your armor - which might be cool.

**Bullet diamagnetic/paramagnetic, magnet part of target : Yea..No.** You would have to induce eddy currents of epic proportions in that bullet - and you only have milliseconds to do it, because the fields would only be strong enough in your very vicinity. Also, no bending here, just slowing it down.

**Bullet ferromagnetic, magnet along path : Yes.** Trivial, you pull the bullet to the side.

**Bullet diamagnetic/paramagnetic (AND good conductor), magnet along path : Yea..mhh.** You need eddy currents, and you need them big. Metals have on the order of .5 kJ/kg heat capacity, so the 2000J of your bullet will heat it by 400°C, which will not melt it, but decrease its conductivity, reining in your ability to induce eddy currents. And your field strength goes down a lot with distance, so the magnets had better be very close.

**Bullet ferromagnetic, magnet behind shooter : Well. No.** You could conceivably build a magnet that trumps the propulsion the bullet experiences from the combustion gases. But this would be a decidedly unhealthy contraption. Humans moving in that kind of field would probably die. And if the field does not get the bullet at the very beginning of its path - it won't ever get it, as the field decreases so fast.

**Bullet diamagnetic/paramagnetic, magnet behind shooter : No!** see above, but worse.

Comment: 2kJ is a lot for a bullet of 10g. I wonder if stopping it midair won't actually melt it - unlike the bullet striking something (and transfer an amount of energy to the target + energy lost in the deformation of the bullet), stopping it using eddy currents will transform its entire energy in heat. (specific heat of copper: 0.385J/(g*C), latent heat of fusion/melting for copper: 206 J/g. A 10g bullet entire made of copper won't melt. If it is lead jacketed in copper, it might)

Comment: the 2kJ@10g come from some hunting-bullet requirements i found on wikipedia. i chose it for the nice numbers. Handguns will be much less energetic, surely

Comment: 16.3g with a muzzle velocity of 715m/s in and AK-47. Gives about 4.16kJ. Copper melting temperature:1085C. Say 1000C raise in temperature then whatever heat to melt 16.3g of copper = 16.3*(206+1000*0.385) = 9633.3J. Meh, still no for an all-copper bullet.

Answer (score 2):

/Could a strong enough magnet deflect or stop a bullet?/

If it were very strong and directly in the path of the bullet, yes.

Comment: You could just move Earth out of the way. Or use a magnet big enough so that everything is 'stopped' inside a singularity.

Comment: Ok @Mazure that is why I stop after just one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in very specific circumstances.  First, you need to make the bullet of iron or other magnetic material.  Then you need to aim it at an electromagnetic launcher (like a railgun) that is capable of running in reverse.  The magnetic fields in the launcher would decelerate the bullet.

This has actually been proposed (IIRC), though I can't find any citations in a quick search.  If for instance you have an electromagnetic launch system on the moon, you can use it to land spacecraft as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely.

Gauss Guns/Coilguns exist:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coilgun

They fire bullets using electromagnets turned on in sequence.

The force, energy, and speed/time/impulse required to stop a bullet is equal to or less than that required to fire it.

Therefore, a bullet travelling directly into the muzzle of such a contraption could be stopped simply by "firing" it backwards.

[image]

Whether you can get the barrel in position, aligned, and triggered at the exact right time is another issue. But the magnets are up to the task.